# Hook to a specific Mongoose model query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have self contained model in invoice.js

```
'use strict';

// load the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var auth_filter = require('../../auth/acl/lib/queryhook');
var invoice_db = mongoose.createConnection(config.mongo.url + '/invoiceDB');

// PROMISE LIBRARY USED FOR ASYNC FLOW
var promise  = require("bluebird");

var Schema     = mongoose.Schema, ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

// define the schema for our invoice details model
var invoicedetailSchema = new Schema({
    //SCHEMA INFO
});
var InvoiceModel = invoice_db.model('InvoiceDetail', invoicedetailSchema);
// create the model for seller and expose it to our app
auth_filter.registerHooks(InvoiceModel);


module.exports = InvoiceModel;
```

I want to hook to the pre query for this model. I am trying to accomplish that using hooks but i am not successful with that. I am registering the hook using auth_filter file as below

```
'use strict';

var hooks = require('hooks'),
    _ = require('lodash');


exports.registerHooks = function (model) {


model.pre('find', function(next,query) {
      console.log('test find');
      next();
   });

model.pre('query', function(next,query) {
      console.log('test query');
      next();
   });

};
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to keep the hooks separate so that I can call for a lot of different models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query [hooks](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) need to be defined on the schema, not the model.  Also, there is no `'query'` hook, and the `query` object is passed to the hook callback as `this` instead of as a parameter.

So change `registerHooks` to be:

```
exports.registerHooks = function (schema) {

    schema.pre('find', function(next) {
          var query = this;
          console.log('test find');
          next();
       });
};
```

And then call it with the schema before creating your model:

```
var invoicedetailSchema = new Schema({
    //SCHEMA INFO
});

auth_filter.registerHooks(invoicedetailSchema);

var InvoiceModel = invoice_db.model('InvoiceDetail', invoicedetailSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This works. Meanwhile I looked at a library called hooks it requires a query object such as mongoose.query to hook. Is there a way to get a query object from a mongoose model and use hooks. I find it much more powerful to do that way. The implementation is straightforward if there is only one model as I am able to hook to mongoose.query. With multiple models it leads to circular reference

Comment: when i try to hook the pre query, it is not firing. I am calling the model using Invoice.find({}).exec()...

Comment: @UmaMaheshwaraa There is no `'query'` hook, only `'find'` and `'findOne'`.  Also, the query object is passed to the hook callback as `this` instead of a parameter. See the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i figured that. But i need to hook it at the model level because i need to know the model name for another function at the 'pre' hook of the find. Using the schema i cannot do so. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633286/what-is-the-best-way-to-hook-to-existing-mongoose-model) If you have any solution please help

Comment: @JohnnyHK Is it possible to create a new hook after creating the model? Elsewhere in the doc using mongoose.model ('MyModel'). Schema